# How to get the selected option from a html <select> & insert into database?

Tags: html, mysql, forms, select

I have made a html page where the data is displayed from another database and i have added extra field of "Status" which have two select option to every student present in the database. My question is how to get the selected['Present' or 'Absent'] data from every student field and insert into a database or get it into a variable

My code is here

http://s11.postimg.org/7s09i58pf/Untitled.png

Here is my databse structure and html page

http://s1.postimg.org/glc705uzj/image.png

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code for `<option>` is incorrect. Instead of `name` in it, use `value`.

Readup: [`<option>` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

To get the value of selected option, you will have to use Javascript:

```
var e = document.querySelector('select[name=status]')
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Then, use AJAX to send this value to your PHP and then add it to your database using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
change the select to capture array
<select name="status[<?php echo $list['stu_id']; ?>]">
instead of 
<select name="status"> 
in the while loop

on submit,  in the backend you will receive status as an array with index as student id

$statuses=$_POST['status'];  // this will give the array of status val of all the students
foreach($statuses as $student_id=>$status_val){
  // update the status for each student based on student id and status val
}
```

Comment: what is $student_id & $status_val.Is it student_id=$list['stu_id']  & what value this $status_val stores

Comment: status val is the value of status for the student, Present or Absent form the select box

Comment: how did i will get that value . if u dont mind can u provide the code .please it would help me a lot

Comment: are you using a form to save the details? if yes, this code has to be put in the form action page.

Comment: <td align="center" valign="middle"> <select name="status[<?php echo $list['stu_id'];$statuses=$_POST['status'];foreach($statuses as $student_id=>$status_val){}?>]">      like this ??????

Comment: the latter code has to be inside the form action page, after u submit the fomr

Comment: Its all hoch poch i am not getting what ur saying but thanks for ur time and so many reply. I am facing problem as i am a student as u can see i am making a attendace record. Thanks a lot

Comment: i understand . i can help you , you can send me a mail with your code and clearly explaining your requirement. this way it is very hectic

Comment: can u provide ur email-id or ping me a blank e-mail on manojsngh786@yahoo.com and i will give u the codes